# Rendring issue in XML UI design in android studio on Mac OSX?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

[image]

I have this Error shown by studio on mac and all from 15 to API 23 is are downloaded and project run fine but it always gave me error while XML to drag and drop.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Clean your project. (Sometimes - the problem occur if Android is unable to find the respective ID from R.java. So its always wise to clean your project and rebuld it.)
2. Check if all the drawables and layouts used in your xml file exist in your project.
3. There may be a missing close tag in xml file.

If you still face the problem, It might be because of missing API details by Android. You can change the API level to API 22 and view your file.
Cannot help more without seeing the code snippet.